# Application not fetching data from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I created a Stationery Management system as my project, using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008, using a local server.

When I published my project as an executable, it is working nicely on my system but raising error on my friend's laptop. He also has VS 2012 and SQL Server 2008 installed.

This is the error I am getting:

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server.The server was not found or was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to allow remote connection.(Provider: SQL Network Interfaces,error 26-Error locating Server/Instance specified)

One more thing, I have made connection with SQL Server in every form of my project. Will this cause it to error?

Comment: I imagine you hard coded the connection string in such a way it only works on your local environment

Comment: What have you tried to fix the issue?  What is your connection method/string?  Is your SQL Server accessible remotely?  Is the SQL server firewalled?  Are network connections enabled?  The default installation configuration usually has TCP/IP connections denied for SQL Server 2008+. Are the credentials correct?

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KHAMMS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Stationery_DataBase;Integrated Security=True");



this is my connection string !!! no it is not accessible remotely.!!!
i dn have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: @Kush If your db is not accessible remotely, how do you expect your application to connect to the "KHAMMS-PC\SQLEXPRESS" database (which I'm assuming is *your* PCs sql express database)

Comment: Yeah this is my pc name. sir actually i made entire project on my pc and it is running through this connection string! and now i want to install on my client PC ! so what will be the possible steps to do it?

one more question when i made exe, will my database tables not integrate with this exe file automaticaly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the protocols are not properly enabled for your server...

Try to do the following:

1. Go to All Programs -> SQL Server 2008 -> SQL Server Config Manager
2. Under SQL Server Network Configuration select Protocols for SQLEXPRESS on the left
3. Select TCP/IP protocol and then right click on properties
4. Under general set Enabled = Yes
5. Restart your SQL Server instance

It should work then...
Bye!